# Where to buy figurines where pranapratishtha was performed?

Tags: ganesha, saraswati, pranapratishtha

I was thinking of performing pranapratishtha for some statuettes (Shree Ganesha and Saraswati) but I learned that it is only for trained priests to do this practice, so I would like to buy them.

Do you know where I can buy them?

Thanks

Comment: You can buy them from sites like Amazon but there is no guaranty that they have done the Prana pratishtha correctly. Also if after energizing an idol that idol is moved from its place the Prana is removed so only objects you can buy which are already energized are Yantras (where Prana stays even if they are moved).